# Firefox in Xubuntu is playing mp2t / .ts / webm video files with a deep / slow / distorted / off audio sound

Tags: sound, xubuntu, firefox, video, pulseaudio

> Firefox Developer Edition latest, v70, Ubuntu 18.04

`mp2t` / `.ts` video plays fine, but audio plays really distorted, very deep like the audio has been slowed down incredibly (even though it plays at same speed). I've tried restarted with no addons to no avail.

Any idea why this file format plays deep sounding from Firefox? It plays perfectly fine when downloaded through mplayer or VLC however, so that leads me to thing there's some issue with a codec or backend lib that firefox may be using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## EDIT: Root issue and solution

It seems that custom user agent strings via about:config value and an extension were directing websites to return an invalid HLS stream for Firefox to read. Disabling these user agent changes has led to the issue resolving itself.

---

Finally got fed up of half of websites not playing audio in Firefox, and decided to debug.

**TL;DR:** Go to `about:config` > `media.mediasource.mp4.enabled` set to **false**

---

## What is media.mediasource config?

The issue was with the entire suite of `media.mediasource.*` configurations, but only the above one seems to be required to disable for videos to start playing.

What is `media.mediasource` and why did it break things?

["Firefox plays the "old" WebM format in its default configuration. Turning on MediaSource will allow you to play the "new" WebM"](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1008271)

---

## Steps to find this solution

1. The first bug I initially found was on bugzilla: [Audio Files Sound Strange on Firefox Platform?](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1244185) from 4 years ago
2. This led me to this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/9h8ulv/distorted_audio_only_when_using_firefox/e6abtd0/) in regards to this config option `media.webspeech.synth.enabled` which made me think that the issue was probably a config media issue.
3. Led me to  [media playback has pitched-down audio](https://github.com/ZusorCode/GoodTwitter/issues/6) and a number of other complaints about firefox and twitter audio in general
4. Finally found what I was looking for with a [Palemoon bug](https://forum.palemoon.org/viewtopic.php?t=16380)

```
I solved a similar issue on my machine as follows...
Edit ==> Preferences ==> Content
and UNcheck "Enable Media Source Extensions (MSE)"
```

In firefox language that is: `media.mediasource.enabled` which solved the problem.

Documenting steps here in case similar issue for someone else comes up.